# Not able to enter text using value() of Javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to enter the password text from browser console using value() of Javascript,but the password is not getting entered in textBox.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('whsOnd').value='test`
```

Attaching the screenshot[image]

Posting Answer so that it may help someone in future who visits here for an answer.

As said by @Amit kumar below in accepted answer,it returns an array so we need to add index to it ,

document.getElementsByClassName('whsOnd')[0].value='test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByClassName give an array so use iteration or indexing on that.

Comment: Thanks ,yeah you're correct